# Keras image binary classification, which class is assigned probability 0 and 1 ? Using Functional API

Tags: keras, deep-learning

When implementing binary classification, the `sigmoid` function is used as activation for the last layer by majority of the people. As I understand the `sigmoid` function gives a probability between 0 and 1 and we set a threshold value (mostly 0.5) to determine the class label.

However I'm confused as to which class does is that probability for ? Say I have two classes `A` and `B` and I get prediction result `p` or `p%` . Is that the probability of **being** class `A` or the probability of **not** being class `A` (i.e `B`).

I apologize if this has been asked here before but I couldn't find it. Since I'm using `Keras Functional API` i cannot use the `predict_classes()` function. Also I mostly use generators for loading my dataset mostly `flow_from_dataframe()` from `ImageDatagenerator` in which you can just provide the class labels or class list. In my case it's two strings in my dataframe "REAL" or "FAKE" .

Also is there a way to set which class I want the probability for ?

Comment: The Image generator traverses all folders in alphabetical order unless mentioned explicitly. So in your case, FAKE will have a probability between 0 to 0.5.

Comment: @clinnsin My answer is not helpful?

Comment: @Frightera yes it was quite helpful. Thanks for explaining the sigmoid function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the probability of being class A or the probability of not
> being class A (i.e B)

Not really. Say, you got 0.8 as an output from sigmoid, so that does not mean your network output probabilities for each classes as sigmoid outputs do not sum up to 1. In other words, having an output 0.8 does not indicate there is a chance of that output belongs to other classes with 0.2 probability.

Also, in **Binary Classification**, with sigmoid network outputs **p(y=1)**. Then by definition of probability **p(y=0) = 1 - p(y=1)**. They add up to one, **only** for **simple binary classification**.

If you want to see the *probabilities* of each class you should use `softmax` activation as its output will sum up to 1. You can interpret `softmax` outputs as probabilities.

On the other hand, these models are **not probabilistic** models, but **deterministic** models. So interpreting outputs of `softmax` as probabilities is common but there is no mathematical connection between them.

> Also is there a way to set which class I want the probability for ?

You can set various of thresholds, i.e mostly 0.5 but that depends on your data and problem. You can change the threshold to see how it effects the AUC-ROC, by interpreting the changes, you can conclude a threshold that fits best for you.

If you want to determine the classes, you can use, note that 0.5 is the threshold and you can change it:

```
predicted_classes = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in preds_sigmoid]
```

Here, if output is bigger than 0.5 than we say it belongs to second class.